# Changing row colour based on a group toggle - SSRS 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2014

One of the tables in my report looks somewhat like:

```
Row       Colour

Total     grey
+Category white
+Category white
+Category white
+Category white
```

It's expandable to

```
Row        Colour

Total      grey
-Category  white
    Item   white
    Item   white
    Item   white
+Category  white
+Category  white
```

'Total' row is grey, the rest is white. I want to be able to change the color of expanded Category row to light grey, but only when it is expanded, to distinguish between item entries, total for the category and total for all categories.

So the final effect would be:

```
Row         Colour

Total       grey
-Category   light grey
    Item    white
    Item    white
    Item    white
+Category   white
```

Apparently there is a textbox.ToggleState property, as shown here
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.textbox.togglestate.aspx

However I do not think it is exposed. ReportItems!name only gives access to the .Value property

I have found this answer on msdn forums

```
Found out how to do this! Use the 'inscope' function.

inscope("groupname") evaluates to TRUE if the group is toggled to expanded and FALSE if it is collapsed.
```

But he was describing SSRS 2005 behaviour. I tried this in 2014 - it seems it no longer works. The Inscope function evaluates to true if the field is part of a group, and false otherwise. Toggling seems to have no effect.

So guys, any ideas?